# root directory of MVC not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to MVC4 (or MVC at all using .NET).  I have my controller and views working fine but if I navigate to 
`http://localhost:<port>` 
I get a 404.  If I go to "
`http://localhost:<port>/MyController` 
everything works fine.  How do I get a default controller for ROOT of the website?

Comment: By default it's `Home` so you can either create a `HomeController` or change the default route to point to your controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your default route is handled by "RouteConfig.cs" which is in the folder "App_Start"

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

In fact, I never use this RouteConfig anymore. I prefer using attributeRouting. It allows to define the routes via an attribute above your controller. http://attributerouting.net/ or more precisely http://attributerouting.net/#defining-routes

Comment: That code is in my RouteConfig.cs.   But if I go to `http://localhost/` I get a 404.  Do I need a Default.cshtml or something in the root?

Comment: I've edited my answer adding "Attribute Routing" that I find easier to use, and which allows more options for your routes. (If you come from php, I think it will be easier for you to use Attribute Routing instead of RouteConfig).

Comment: I will check that out.  Until a year ago I had never did any web development in Windows.  Always worked on Linux boxes with PHP.  I'm liking some of the things that .NET makes easy but other things I think could be more simple.  I guess I'm still in transformation.  :)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what your 'root controller' is called and what the name of your landing action is. if it is `MyController`.`Index()` then you would do

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "My", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

Comment: Ok, I created a Home controller and view and it's working.  I assumed that any controller called home would require `http://localhost/Home` to work.  Thanks for the help.  I created a Empty project because I want to learn not have VS create most of it for me :)   Thanks a lot for your help.